# Are there any WordPress based e-commerce plugins that allow me to attach meta data per order?

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce

I'm currently using [WP Shopping Cart](http://www.instinct.co.nz/e-commerce/).

Per order of a product, I need to attach some meta data such as size, frame options and frame colour. These different options change the price of the end product.

My first idea was to simply add a new product via the database each time, adding the necessary info to the product description and changing the price accordingly. However, this sounds like an ugly hack that will only lead me to problems down the track.

Is there any WordPress ecommerce system that allows this, or do you have a better solution to my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes a bit late but... [Getshopped](http://getshopped.org/resources/docs/building-your-store/variations/) seems to meet you needs.

They call the product meta *variations* and I've linked you to the specific page.

Hope it helps!